# Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not return

Tags: java

LSPcalc is an exe...followed by some arguments. The process never returns.

---

```
  Process procs =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"./LSPcalc","U",SN,Penalty}); 

 System.out.println("Done initializing LSPcalc");

 StreamReaderThread stdout1 = new StreamReaderThread(procs.getInputStream(), "OUT");
 StreamReaderThread stderr1 = new StreamReaderThread(procs.getErrorStream(), "ERR");

  try{

     stdout1.start();
     stderr1.start();
     procs.waitFor();
     stdout1.join();
     stderr1.join();

 }catch(InterruptedException ie){
    ie.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: So does it not print the text?

Comment: And `StreamReaderThread` is what? Also, why don't use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: If you run the exact command in a DOS box, does the command complete or keep running and waiting for user interaction? If it keeps running and waiting for the user to type something, that will keep it running when your Java code is executing it too, and the threads will never complete and the join() calls will never finish.